# C#. Как обработать событие нажатие мыши на иконку в панели задач windows?

Tags: c#, winforms

При сворачивании моего приложения происходят определённые махинации, после которых окно приложения просто так не развернётся обратно. Нужно или поймать событие нажатия на иконку в панели задач, или переопределить действия, при нажатии иконки приложения, только вот где найти это событие и т.д. я не знаю, если кто сталкивался, отпишитесь пожалуйста. Обработка события изменения WindowsState Или SizeChanged не подходят.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.click?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @KuzCode спасибо конечно, но я не про область уведомлений говорил